# Need help to replicate .htaccess mod_rewrite redirection function in php like Wordpress

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

We all know that wordpress have simple .htaccess code like below
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

```
# only rewrite if the requested file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 

# pass the rest of the request into index.php to handle     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But if I redirect all requests to index.php, I think it becomes pretty cumbersome to handle every rewrite in php. Currently I have a logic in mind, like maintain a db table with all valid redirections. But still I don't know how to handle rules likes ([0-9]+).

If anyone has implemented something like this before or has a logic in mind, can you please guide me in this matter

The sole purpose am doing this, is because I want flexibility in adding/deleting categories in the menu of my site. I don't want to go to .htaccess every time and edit it at all places. I want to create more like a CMS where user can add delete categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to set up php based routing the basic idea is that you do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files with extensions other than .html
# this way if you want you can append the .html to dynamic pages
# which wont really exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

// redirect everything to your front controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Notice how you just make everythign go to `index.php` but you dont rewrite any of the variables or anything. This is because you will work out what to based on the pattern of the URL with php. In order to do this youll need to implement a router. Basically a router takes a request and matches it against a pattern and then determines any parameters based on the pattern.

There are existing libraries out there to do this for you. For example [`Zend_Controller_Router`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot prodigitalson, but could you shed more light on what exactly a 'router' is? Are there any good examples of router implemention, similar to my purpose, you could share? Thanks again :)

Comment: For examples you can check out most of the major PHP frameworks ([Zend](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Fbranches%2Frelease-1.11%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FController%2FRouter%2FRewrite.php), [Symfony](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/routing/sfPatternRouting.class.php), [Cake](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php), [CI](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/d406084f5bef/system/core/Router.php), etc..), they all have some kind of implementation.

Comment: Thanks prodigitalson..will check it out

Comment: can zend_framework_router used independently without the zend MVC framework?

Comment: It would probably be eaiser to write your own if you dont want to use the entire `Zend_Controller` component. You could though, use it as an example to do that. If you google aroun there may be an independent routing framework you can just wire in to an existing project, but i havent seen one. In fact id be interested to know if you find one :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question, WordPress already handles all this for you. Unless you mean you aren't using WordPress? In which case yes, you can do it either way. What kind of URL structure do you want? You could write a rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$  categories.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

To make a URL like domain.com/category/dogs rewrite to domain.com/categories.php?cat=dogs. Obviously you can adjust this to your liking, and write a few more similar rules for tags, posts etc.

Handling routing in php would be a more dynamic and 'elegant' solution. You could try using a framework like CodeIgniter, this will manage routes for you automatically and make it easy to define custom routes. Probably better than writing a bunch of .htaccess rules.

Comment: Thanks Christian, but I have urls of the format http://sitename.com/entertainment/,http://sitename.com/tech/,http://sitename.com/news/  etc...and in future can add more categories also. So i dont want to handle it in .htaccess, want to handle it in php...and yes, am not using wordpress..its my own custom website

Comment: In that case, you can either use a framework like CodeIgniter to manage the routes for you, or you could write a generic .htaccess rule (like RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  categories.php?cat=$1&post=$2) which would allow you to use the URL structure you indicated.

Comment: Thanks again Christian, but can we simply just use the router part of Codeigniter framework alone? I dont want to use the entire framwork

Comment: You might be able to, but it would probably take less time to write your own or convert your site to CI :p. You could try [konstrukt](https://github.com/troelskn/konstrukt), I've never used it, but it might do what you want. Otherwise, one of my favourite methods of learning, go through WordPress or CI source and find out how their routing works, then write your own :)

Comment: yeah, but from whatever i have seen, it looks pretty complicated and intimidating :( lol